# What is the meaning of 128 bit key in AES

Tags: encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am new to encryption methods and i want to know what is the meaning of 128 bit key. Does it mean the key has 128 characters or when we convert key to the binary, and then that binary has 128 digits or cipher that created using key and plain text has 128 characters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is 128 (binary) bits. That's all it means.

[AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) supports key sizes of 128, 192, or 256 bits.

AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits, which means it en/decrypts data in chunks of 16 bytes at a time. The plaintext/cipher text can be any length of course (and is [padded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) out to a multiple of 16 bytes).

Good crypto implementations will use a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) which takes a password (or keyfile, etc) of *any length*, and generates a key suitable for the encryption algorithm in question.

Comment: Thank You. One more thing, does it mean that we can provide key that has any number of characters ?

Comment: No, the *key* is **exactly** 128 bits. As I said, a *password* used to *derive* the key can be of any length.

Comment: Key means secret key ?

Comment: Yes. AES is a symmetric-key cryptosystem, meaning the same key is used for both encryption and decryption. You never share it. (Unlike public-key crypto, where there is a private/public key pair - used in algorithms like RSA).

Comment: Ok ok thank you Jonathon. I found the example code form the internet. http://www.software-architect.net/articles/using-strong-encryption-in-java/introduction.html
And now i am going to try that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It represents the length of the encryption or decryption key in binaries basically 0's and 1's. It doesn't necessarily have 128 characters but it has 128 bits and also it would take 2^128 combinations to break the encryption key.